# Toll booth bill by mail

Tags: mail, tolls

About 3-4 weeks ago I was passing through Maryland/Virginia and I was a dollar short on cash for the toll payment. So the person in the toll booth said that they would take a picture and mail the bill to whomever the vehicle is registered to (that is me). I said ok and drove on. I still haven't recieved the bill, is there anyway to trace it?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Whoops, no idea why it cut the text at the end.

Comment: Some toll authorities send out bills by mail very infrequently.  A pay-by-plate system is in place on the Massachusetts Turnpike, where all cars without a transponder are photographed and mailed a bill.  I got a bill from them recently;  it covered all my usage for the past six months.

Comment: Was this in Maryland or Virginia?

Comment: @RobertColumbia I think it was Maryland as I can't an $8 toll on the I95 in Virginia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most toll authorities that allow billing by mail have websites where you can look up your account by license plate number.  It can sometimes take several weeks for what you owe to appear on the site.

I'd suggest googling "toll" and the name of your bridge to find out the toll authority responsible, and there you should be able to find the details of how they do billings, and figure out the status of your account.

In some situations I've found that bills are never sent to vehicle owners from certain jurisdictions (e.g. I found out by experience that the Highway 407 toll authority in Toronto and the Washington state toll authority in the Seattle area don't bill vehicles from Saskatchewan, presumably because they see so few of them that they choose not to pay the fees to get license information from such vehicles.)

Comment: I was northbound on the I-95 and the toll was $8 and according to http://www.i95exitguide.com/tolls/ it might be JFK Memorial Highway (I-95)
Baltimore, MD to MD/DE State Line. Who can I call for this, Maryland ez pass?

Comment: @Newton:  My guess would be the [Maryland Transportation Authority.](http://www.mdta.maryland.gov/Toll_Facilities/qanda.html#complaints)

Comment: @Newton http://www.mdta.maryland.gov/ETL/Toll_Rate_Schedule.html According to this, you should get a bill in three to six weeks, at 1.5 times the cash toll rate.  It does not appear that there is any way to look up your video toll account online.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie this helps, i guess i will call them after every week to check

Comment: @Newton I wouldn't bother calling, unless after six or seven weeks you've heard nothing.  Also, make sure the address on file with your state/province's motor licensing authority is up to date, as that is where the bill will go.